# how to arrange the item of a list into series arrangement

Tags: c#, list

I have a list of data which contains of random data with combination of string and number:

```
List<String> Data1 = new List<String>()
{
  "1001A",
  "1002A",
  "1003A",
  "1004A",
  "1015A",
  "1016A",
  "1007A",
  "1008A",
  "1009A",
};
```

I want this data to arrange into series like this:

```
1001A - 1004A, 1007A - 1009A, 1015A, 1016A
```

for every more than 2 counts of data series the output shall be have "-" between the first count and the last count of series, the other non series data will be just added to the last part and all together will separated by ",".

I'd already made some codes only to arrange the data series by the last char of it:

```
string get_REVISIONMARK = "A";

var raw_serries = arrange_REVISIONSERIES.Where(p => p[p.Length -       1].ToString() == get_REVISIONMARK) .OrderBy(p => p[p.Length - 1) .ThenBy(p => p.Substring(0, p.Length - 1)).ToList();
```

> just ignore the last char I'd already have function for that, and my problem only about the arrangement of the numbers, the length of data is not fixed. for other example of output "1001A - 1005A, 301A, 32A"
>
> I had another sample of my codes this works fine to me, but for me its so lazy code.

```
for (int c1 = 0; c1 < list_num.Count; c1++)
{
    if (list_num[c1] != 0)
    {
         check1 = list_num[c1];
         for (int c2 = 0; c2 < list_num.Count; c2++)
         {
              if (check1 == list_num[c2])
              {
                  list_num[c2] = 0;
                  check1 += 1;
                  list_series.Add(arrange_REVISIONSERIES[c2]);
              }
         }
         check1 = 0;
         if (list_series.Count > 2)
         {
             res_series.Add(list_series[0] + " to " +list_series[list_series.Count - 1]);
             list_series.Clear();
         }
         else
         {
             if (list_series.Count == 1)
             {
                 res_series.Add(list_series[0]);
                 list_series.Clear();
             }
             else
             {
                 res_series.Add(list_series[0] + "," + list_series[1]);
                 list_series.Clear();
             }
        }
    }
}
var combine_res = String.Join(",", res_series);
MessageBox.Show(combine_res);
```

this codes work fine for the series number ...

Comment: Is there a fixed pattern for your data eg. always four digits followed by one uppercase letter?

Comment: have you tried anything before asking a question?

Comment: `var raw_serries = arrange_REVISIONSERIES.Where(p => p[p.Length - 1].ToString() == get_REVISIONMARK)
                        .OrderBy(p => p[p.Length - 1)
                            .ThenBy(p => p.Substring(0, p.Length - 1)).ToList();`

this is my example of my codes to arrange the list by the last char letter @wudzik

Comment: just ignore the last char I'd already have function for that, and my problem only about the arrangement of the numbers, the length of data is not fixed. for other example of output "1001A - 1005A, 301A, 32A" @Pilgerstorfer Franz

Comment: @BadIdea post it in your question, it will help others

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A possible solution (working with current set of values), Please follow the steps below

Declare a class level string list as

```
    public List<String> data_result = new List<string>();
```

Create a function to iterate through input string list (input string declared inside, named 'data')

```
    public void ArrangeList()
    {
        List<String> data = new List<string>() { "1001A", "1002A", "1003A", 
        "1004A", "1015A", "1016A", "1007A", "1008A", "1009A", "1017A" };
        List<int> data_int = data.Select(a => Convert.ToInt32(a.Substring(0,
        a.Length - 1))).OrderBy(b => b).ToList();
        int initializer = 0, counter = 0;
        int finalizer = 0;

        foreach (var item in data_int)
        {
            if (initializer == 0)
            { initializer = item; continue; }
            else
            {
                counter++;
                if (item == initializer + counter)
                    finalizer = item;
                else
                {
                    LogListing(initializer, finalizer);
                    initializer = item;
                    finalizer = item;
                    counter = 0;
                }
            }
        }
        LogListing(initializer, finalizer);
    }
```

Create a function which just logs the result into data_result string list.

```
    public void LogListing(int initializer, int finalizer)
    {
        if (initializer != finalizer)
        {
            if (finalizer == initializer + 1)
            {
                data_result.Add(initializer + "A");
                data_result.Add(finalizer + "A");
            }
            else
                data_result.Add(initializer + "A - " + finalizer + "A");

        }
        else
            data_result.Add(initializer + "A");
    }
```

---

It perfectly generates the result list as

---

[image]

Thumb-up if you like

Comment: thanks and nice work , but the 1015A - 1016A supposed to be like this 1015A, 1016A like the given example output above ...

Answer (score 0):

I'm making two assumptions:

1. The list is already ordered
2. The non-numeric characters can be ignored

You will get the results in the `results` variable:

```
void Main()
{
    List<String> Data1 = new List<String>()
    {
      "1001A",
      "1002A",
      "1003A",
      "1004A",
      "1015A",
      "1016A",
      "1007A",
      "1008A",
      "1009A",
    };

    var accu = new List<List<Tuple<int, string>>>();

    foreach (var data in Data1)
    {
        if (accu.Any(t => t.Any(d => d.Item1 == (ToInt(data) - 1))))
        {
            var item = accu.First(t => t.Any(d => d.Item1 == (ToInt(data) - 1)));
            item.Add(new Tuple<int, string>(ToInt(data), data));
        }
        else
        {
            accu.Add(new List<Tuple<int, string>>{ new Tuple <int, string>(ToInt(data), data)});
        }
    }

    var results = new List<string>();

    results.AddRange(accu.Where(g => g.Count > 2).Select(g => string.Format("{0} - {1}", g.First().Item2, g.Last().Item2)));
    results.AddRange(accu.Where(g => g.Count <= 2).Aggregate(new List<string>(), (total, current) => { total.AddRange(current.Select(i => i.Item2)); return total; } ));
}

private static Regex digitsOnly = new Regex(@"[^\d]");

public static int ToInt(string literal)
{
    int i;
    int.TryParse(digitsOnly.Replace(literal, ""), out i);
    return i;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A linqy solution:

```
    char get_REVISIONMARK = 'A';

    var res = arrange_REVISIONSERIES.Select(s => new { Rev = s[s.Length - 1], Value = int.Parse(s.Substring(0, s.Length - 1)), Org = s })
        .Where(d => d.Rev == get_REVISIONMARK).OrderBy(d => d.Value)
        .Select((val, ind) => new { Index = ind, Org = val.Org, Value = val.Value }).GroupBy(a => a.Value - a.Index)
        .Select(gr=>gr.ToList()).OrderBy(l=>l.Count > 2 ? 0 : 1 ).Aggregate(new List<string>(), (list, sublist) =>
        {
            if (sublist.Count > 2)
                list.Add(sublist[0].Org + " - " + sublist[sublist.Count - 1].Org);
            else
                list.AddRange(sublist.Select(a => a.Org));
            return list;
        });
```

The first lines are basically the same as the code you already have (filter on revision and sort), but with the difference that the subvalues are stored in an anonymous type. You could do the same on the pre ordered list, but since splitting the string would be done twice I've included it in the total.

Then a select with index (`.Select((val, ind) =>`) is made to get value/index pairs. This is done to be able to get the sequences based on an old t-sql row_number trick: for each 'group' the difference between value and index is the same `.GroupBy(a => a.Value - a.Index)`

After that, normally you'd be as good as done, but since you only want to make sequences of 2 and longer, we make sublists out of the groupby values and do the ordering beforehand to make sure the ranges come for the eventual single elements `.Select(gr=>gr.ToList()).OrderBy(l=>l.Count > 2 ? 0 : 1 )`

Finally, the list is created of the groups. Several options, but I like to use Aggregate for that. The seed is the resulting list, and the aggregate simply adds to that (where subranges > 2 are cummulated and for single elements and pairs, the single elements are added)

Answer (score 0):

So given your starting data:

```
List<String> arrange_REVISIONSERIES = new List<String>()
{
    "1001A",
    "1002A",
    "1003A",
    "1004A",
    "1015A",
    "1016A",
    "1007A",
    "1008A",
    "1009A",
};
```

I do this first:

```
var splits =
    arrange_REVISIONSERIES
        .Select(datum => new
        {
            value = int.Parse(datum.Substring(0, datum.Length - 1)),
            suffix = datum.Substring(datum.Length - 1, 1),
        })
        .OrderBy(split => split.suffix)
        .ThenBy(split => split.value)
        .ToArray();
```

That's basically the same as your `raw_serries`, but orders the number part as a number. It seems to me that you need it as a number to make the range part work.

I then do this to compute the groupings:

```
var results =
    splits
    .Skip(1)
    .Aggregate(
        new[]
                {
                    new
                    {
                        start = splits[0].value,
                        end = splits[0].value,
                        suffix = splits[0].suffix
                    }
                }.ToList(),
        (a, s) =>
        {
            if (a.Last().suffix == s.suffix && a.Last().end + 1 == s.value)
            {
                a[a.Count - 1] = new
                {
                    start = a.Last().start,
                    end = s.value,
                    suffix = s.suffix
                };
            }
            else
            {
                a.Add(new
                {
                    start = s.value,
                    end = s.value,
                    suffix = s.suffix
                });
            }
            return a;
        })
    .Select(r => r.start == r.end
        ? String.Format("{0}{1}", r.end, r.suffix)
        : (r.start + 1 == r.end
            ? String.Format("{0}{2}, {1}{2}", r.start, r.end, r.suffix)
            : String.Format("{0}{2} - {1}{2}", r.start, r.end, r.suffix)))
    .ToArray();
```

And finally, this to create a single string:

```
var result = String.Join(", ", results);
```

That gives me:

> 1001A - 1004A, 1007A - 1009A, 1015A, 1016A

This code nicely works with data containing different suffixes.

Comment: thanks and nice work , but the 1015A - 1016A supposed to be like this 1015A, 1016A like the given example output above ...